# What does this word written on Avengers Tower signify?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

In episode 5 of *Loki* series when we see the void we see many things dumped there like

> USS Eldridge ship, a helicarrier, a sphinx along with an Avengers tower with QENG written on it.

What does this signify?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's possible that this is a nod to the main (Earth-616) Marvel (comics) universe on which the Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth-199999) is based.

In the Earth-616 universe [Qeng Enterprises](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Qeng_Enterprises_(Earth-616)), run by the villain "Mr. Gryphon," purchased what had previously been the Avengers Tower, possibly to further his plot to destroy the Avengers.

There is [already speculation](https://www.inverse.com/entertainment/loki-episode-5-easter-egg-reveals-another-major-kang-the-conqueror-connection) that this means that [Kang the Conqueror](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kang_the_Conqueror) will soon show up as a new villain.  (Mr. Gryphon and Kang are aspects or versions of the same being, but stranded in different times or something.  It's complicated.)

Comment: out of curiosity, where/when was the MCU's number confirmed? I remember there was something in homecoming, but I thought that was generally assumed to have ben made up by Mysterio

Comment: I don't know if this was its first mention but Wikipedia cites a screenrant article from 2013 titled "Kevin Feige on 'Iron Man 3' and the Shared Marvel Movie Universe" as the origin of the Earth-199999 designation. Do note the number has no meaning in-universe, its an arbitrary number the comics use to differentiate the many realities that exist for our sakes but for the inhabitants of the many realities their Earth is the only one that matters.

Comment: @Gatchwar Actually, Earth-* designations were used in *Spider-Verse*, including 616.